# Почему и как это работает?(Heap and Stack)

Tags: c++, c

Правильно ли я понимаю, что массив создается и на куче и на стеке, но как он выбирает, куда ему класть значения. Или он кладет первые три элемента в куче, так как в первых трех элементах лежит адрес на кучу, а остальные на стеке.

```
int c[6];

*c = (int)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

c[1] = 5;
c[2] = 3;
c[5] = 53;




printf("%d %d %d", c[1], c[2], c[5]);
```

Comment: "массив создается и на куче и на стеке" - как он может быть в двух местах одновременно?

Comment: E вас один массив - в стеке, массив  `c`. Второй якобы массив из трех `int` у вас выделяется в куче, но все, что вы с ним делаете - это преобразуете его адрес в `int` (если получится) и сохраняете его в `c[0]`. Все.

Comment: Ваш `malloc` с приведением результата к типу `int` - это какая-то бессмыслица, а не "создание массива в куче". Отвечая на вопрос из заголовка: это *никак* не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int c[6];

*c = (int)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

В стеке выделяется массив на 6 целых знаковых 32битных(как правило, но не обязательно, может быть и 16 бит) чисел, затем по индексу 0 этого массива присваивается число - адрес в памяти, который указывает на только что выделенный в куче массив на три таких же числа.

Выражение вида `*(c + n)` эквивалентно `с[n]`, в вашем случае `n` равно `0`.

Правда, непонятно, зачем вы присваиваете элементу одного массива адрес другого...

Comment: Кто сказал что 32-х? Гарантируется же что не меньше 16 бит, чтобы не меньше 32-х было, надо long использовать

Comment: Верно, но все-таки в 99% случаев сегодня это будет 32 бита. Поправлю, спасибо.

Answer (score -3):

У вас один массив - в стеке, массив c. Второй якобы массив из трех int у вас выделяется в куче, но все, что вы с ним делаете - это преобразуете его адрес в int (если получится) и сохраняете его в c[0]. Все